# Is there any special package for algebraic geometry, algebraic number theory and commutative algebra?

Tags: math-mode, packages

People who are familiar with algebraic geometry, algebraic number theory and commutative algebra, know that it takes long commands to type to get special symbols. For example norms and trace specifying the base field and the extension field. I want to know if there is a package specially made for algebra (especially algebraic geometry, algebraic number theory and commutative algebra).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There might be, but even if there is, you will probably be dissatisfied with it since it will never quite fit your own notational taste. It’s usually better to create your own functions that fit your personal choice of notation. For this, you can use e.g. `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` or create advanced commands using `xparse`. Otherwise, I can mention my own package, `semantex`, whose purpose is to make it easier to create commands of the type you want. The manual has several sections with examples from commutative algebra and algebraic geometry.